# Altium Single Sheet BOM Generation

Tags: altium, bom

Apart from moving each sheet out of my Altium Project and generating a BOM for each of them, is there a way to generate a separate BOM for each Schematic Page in my Altium Project? Or alternatively, to group the BOM into a separate section for each sheet on one BOM?

I would like to know what value each of the logical units (separate Sheets) contributes to the total BOM Cost, e.g. Power Supply Sheet cost = $4.00, MCU Page = $5.00 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of ways that I know to do it, but there could be more.

1) You can use an output job.  Then create a new report output for each schematic page by setting the data source to that page.

2) Add schematic page information to each line item in your BOM.  Using an output job, you can add the parameters DocumentFullPathAndName, DocumentName, and DocumentNumber.  Between these fields, you should be able to generate a BOM for the whole project, then sort the data into excel for each sheet.

I'm using Altium 17, but these features have been around for a while.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that worked great! Note that you can also select which sheets to include in the BOM by clicking on the "filter" icon on the "DocumentName" column in the BOM generation dialog. This will save you a step of having to edit the exported excel file.